# how to automate when altering jobs in Always on availability groups?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2016, automation

I often have to alter jobs i.e. adding steps, changing the stored procedures the job calls, etc. and I always need to do the same thing on all servers in my availability group.

when dealing with jobs, the `job_id` in server A is not the same `job_id` in server B for instance, so I always have to find the `job_id` manually.

**how could I automate this?**

below is an example where I add an extra step to an existing job. I need to have a look at all the servers in the availability group and go server by server finding the `job_id` and doing the changes.

```
-- do a job alteration on all the servers in the availability group
-- get all servers in the availability group

-- need to be on the primary server in order to run the following:
select ar.replica_server_name,
ars.role_desc,
ar.failover_mode_desc,
ars.synchronization_health_desc,
ars.operational_state_desc,
CASE ars.connected_state
WHEN 0 THEN 'Disconnected'
WHEN 1 THEN 'Connected'
ELSE ''
END as ConnectionState

from sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars

inner join sys.availability_replicas ar 
        on ars.replica_id = ar.replica_id
       and ars.group_id = ar.group_id


--=========================================================
-- ON THE_SERVER_01
--=========================================================

USE [msdb]
GO

sp_help_job @job_name=N'JUNO - Update Time Expired Applicants'
--JUNO - Update Time Expired Applicants

--3868EB02-BC27-4F2C-9593-7526705FB1DA
GO

/****** Object:  Step [Update Applicants]    Script Date: 02/08/2017 13:56:28 ******/
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobstep 
@job_id=N'3868EB02-BC27-4F2C-9593-7526705FB1DA', @step_id=1
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep 
@job_id=N'3868EB02-BC27-4F2C-9593-7526705FB1DA', @step_name=N'Update Applicants', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=4, 
        @on_success_step_id=2, 
        @on_fail_action=4, 
        @on_fail_step_id=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'EXEC usp_upd_applicationStatusTimeExpired', 
        @database_name=N'JUNOCore', 
        @output_file_name=N'E:\Jobs Output\JUNO_-_Update_Time_Expired_Applicants_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))_Update_Applicants.txt', 
        @flags=20
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep 
@job_id=N'3868EB02-BC27-4F2C-9593-7526705FB1DA', 
@step_name=N'run the peocedure [app].[usp_upd_applicationStatusTimeExpired]', 
        @step_id=2, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'
EXEC [APCore].[app].[usp_upd_applicationStatusTimeExpired]
', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=20
GO

--=========================================================
-- ON THE_SERVER_01
--=========================================================


USE [msdb]
GO

sp_help_job @job_id=N'216381ee-a2da-4fa5-9ca8-aad98dd2ad50'
--JUNO - Update Time Expired Applicants


GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobstep 
@job_id=N'216381ee-a2da-4fa5-9ca8-aad98dd2ad50', 
@step_id=1
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=N'216381ee-a2da-4fa5-9ca8-aad98dd2ad50', 
@step_name=N'Update Applicants', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=4, 
        @on_success_step_id=2, 
        @on_fail_action=4, 
        @on_fail_step_id=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'EXEC usp_upd_applicationStatusTimeExpired', 
        @database_name=N'JUNOCore', 
        @output_file_name=N'E:\Jobs Output\JUNO_-_Update_Time_Expired_Applicants_$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(STEPID))_Update_Applicants.txt', 
        @flags=20
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep 
@job_id=N'216381ee-a2da-4fa5-9ca8-aad98dd2ad50', 
@step_name=N'run the peocedure [app].[usp_upd_applicationStatusTimeExpired]', 
        @step_id=2, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'
EXEC [APCore].[app].[usp_upd_applicationStatusTimeExpired]
', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=20
GO
```

Comment: One option https://dbatools.io/functions/copy-sqljob/

Comment: YES! Love dbatools!!

Comment: @SQL_Hacker and why you did not mention those tools in your answer then?

Comment: I forgot about them, and at my present job, I cannot use them, so I rely on "basic" t-sql to get stuff done. :)

Comment: Are you not allowed to use powershell at all?  Pure TSQL would make this unnecessarily challenging.

Comment: @JonathanFite not at all, it is just I wouldn't know where to start with it, but I plan to change this reality soon

Answer (score 2):

Finding the job_id is not necessary if the job is named the same on all replicas. You can use the @job_name parameter, and never have to know the job_id. See this link for an example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-delete-jobstep-transact-sql.
A more specific answer to your question is to use `@job_id = N'<job_name here>`.

Comment: that's true indeed, I just use job_id  when I use scripts generated by sql server